# Backbone with requirejs - "model is not defined" when passing to view

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am getting a JS error "Uncaught ReferenceError: model is not defined" when rendering a view from within another view.

I have a list view:

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'views/action',
    'collections/actionlist',
    'text!templates/actionlist.html'],

function($, Backbone, _, actionView, actionList, template){

var someactions = [
    { the_action: "Contact 1", due: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", list: "0123456789" },
    { the_action: "Contact 2", due: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", list: "0123456789" },
    { the_action: "Contact 3", due: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", list: "0123456789" }
];

var actionlistView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#main',
    template: _.template(template),

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new actionList(someactions);            
        this.collection.on("add", this.renderAction, this);
    },

    events: {
        "click #add": "addAction"
    },

    render: function () {
        var $el = $('#main')

        $el.html(this.template);

        // Get Actions
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (action) {
            this.renderAction(action);
        }, this);

    },

    renderAction: function (action) {
        var theAction = new actionView({ model: action });
        $('#actionlist').append(theAction.render().el);
    },

    addAction: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = {};

        $('#addAction').children("input").each(function(i, el){
            if ($(el).val() !== "") {
                formData[el.id] = $(el).val();
            }
        });

        this.collection.create(formData);
    }
});

return actionlistView;
});
```

The actionView that this calls in the renderAction function is:

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'models/action',
    'text!templates/action.html'], 

function($, Backbone, _, actionModel, template){

var actionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagname: 'li',
    template: _.template(template),

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model)); // ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
        return this;
    }
});

return actionView;
});
```

I get the error on the line "this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));" when trying to render the first actionView.

I am stumped!! What am I missing?

ActionView Template as requested:

```
    <b class="name"><%=model.get("the_action")%></b> - <%=model.get("due")%> - 
    <em>from <%=model.get("list")%></em>
```

Comment: Can you also post your actionView  template?

Comment: You should try call the template with `this.$el.html(this.template({model: this.model }));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are better off calling model.toJSON() in the template and referencing the json in the template.

From this:

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
```

To this:

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Then reference 'due' and 'list' in the template directly:

```
<b class="name"><%=the_action%></b> - <%=due%> - 
    <em>from <%=list%></em>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was the one!